# How to use androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView with tools:listitem?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, preview, androidx, android-tools-namespace

How to use `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` with `tools:listitem`?
I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewActors"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_actor"
    tools:itemCount="5"
    tools:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:scrollbars="horizontal"
    tools:spanCount="2"/>
```

but *Design* tab doesn't show preview:

[image]

And if I change `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` in this layout to `ListView`, the preview works:

[image]

Comment: I copy past your code and is when I add this line `tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"` in my code I have the same issue (don't see my items) so you can remove it if is not needed

Comment: @crammeur, but I have this issue and without this line

Comment: I see in the display of android studio this `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager` can explain why you can't have the display. So he can't display because he not find this

Comment: Do you use `implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-beta01'` or `implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-alpha1'` because when I use alpha I can see but when I change I don't see preview

Comment: try to clean the project and rebuild it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From your code it seems that your recyclerview is the root element of the XML, and is missing the reference from xmlns:tools

Try to use another root element, as a constraint layout or even just layout as per example of [google sunflowerapp](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower):

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/plant_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_normal"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_normal"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:context="com.google.samples.apps.sunflower.GardenActivity"
            tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_plant" />

</layout>
```